# Transform Java Future into a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, future

Java 8 introduces `CompletableFuture`, a new implementation of Future that is composable (includes a bunch of thenXxx methods). I'd like to use this exclusively, but many of the libraries I want to use return only non-composable `Future` instances.

Is there a way to wrap up a returned `Future` instances inside of a `CompleteableFuture` so that I can compose it?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is a way, but you won't like it. The following method transforms a `Future<T>` into a `CompletableFuture<T>`:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> makeCompletableFuture(Future<T> future) {
  if (future.isDone())
    return transformDoneFuture(future);
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
      if (!future.isDone())
        awaitFutureIsDoneInForkJoinPool(future);
      return future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // Normally, this should never happen inside ForkJoinPool
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      // Add the following statement if the future doesn't have side effects
      // future.cancel(true);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  });
}

private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> transformDoneFuture(Future<T> future) {
  CompletableFuture<T> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
  T result;
  try {
    result = future.get();
  } catch (Throwable ex) {
    cf.completeExceptionally(ex);
    return cf;
  }
  cf.complete(result);
  return cf;
}

private static void awaitFutureIsDoneInForkJoinPool(Future<?> future)
    throws InterruptedException {
  ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(new ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker() {
    @Override public boolean block() throws InterruptedException {
      try {
        future.get();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      return true;
    }
    @Override public boolean isReleasable() {
      return future.isDone();
    }
  });
}
```

Obviously, the problem with this approach is, that for each *Future*, a thread will be blocked to wait for the result of the *Future*--contradicting the idea of futures. In some cases, it might be possible to do better. However, in general, there is no solution without actively wait for the result of the *Future*.

Comment: Ha, that's exactly what I wrote before thinking that there must be a better way. But, I guess not

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't this solution eat one of the threads of the "common pool", just for waiting? Those "common pool" threads should never block... hmmmm...

Comment: @Peti: You are right. However, the point is, if you are most likely doing something wrong, regardless whether you are using the _common pool_ or an _unbounded thread pool_.

Comment: It might not be perfect, but using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, new SinglethreadExecutor())` would at least not block the common pool threads.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm not familiar with the "common pool". Why is this approach bad? Are you saying that `future.get` should never be called?

Comment: Please, just never do that

Comment: The common pool is a thread pool with a small amount of threads (usually 1 per processor core) and it's one pool shared with the whole JVM, and it's meant for non-blocking operations. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` runs in the common pool unless a different `ExecutorService` is passed as a parameter and `future.get()` is a blocking operation. So you should never do this.

Comment: @MikeFHay I think employing `FJP.ManagedBlocker` will result in better utilization than `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, t -> newSingleThreadExecutor())`. I've updated the code in the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 75):

If the library you want to use also offers a callback style method in addition to the Future style, you can provide it a handler that completes the CompletableFuture without any extra thread blocking. Like so:

```
    AsynchronousFileChannel open = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("/some/file"));
    // ... 
    CompletableFuture<ByteBuffer> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<ByteBuffer>();
    open.read(buffer, position, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Void>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(Integer result, Void attachment) {
            completableFuture.complete(buffer);
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(exc);
        }
    });
    completableFuture.thenApply(...)
```

Without the callback the only other way I see solving this is to use a polling loop that puts all your `Future.isDone()` checks on a single thread and then invoking complete whenever a Future is gettable.

Comment: I am using Apache Http async library which accepts FutureCallback. It made my life easy :)

Answer (score 70):

If your `Future` is the result of a call to an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) method (e.g. `submit()`), the easiest would be to use the [`CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable, Executor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) method instead.

From

```
Runnbale myTask = ... ;
Future<?> future = myExecutor.submit(myTask);
```

to

```
Runnbale myTask = ... ;
CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(myTask, myExecutor);
```

The `CompletableFuture` is then created "natively".

EDIT: Pursuing comments by @SamMefford corrected by @MartinAndersson, if you want to pass a `Callable`, you need to call [`supplyAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), converting the `Callable<T>` into a `Supplier<T>`, e.g. with:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try { return myCallable.call(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw new CompletionException(ex); } // Or return default value
}, myExecutor);
```

Because `T Callable.call() throws Exception;` throws an exception and `T Supplier.get();` doesn't, you have to catch the exception so prototypes are compatible.

### A note on exception handling

The `get()` method doesn't specify a `throws`, which means it should not throw a *checked* exception. However, *unchecked* exception can be used. The code in `CompletableFuture` shows that `CompletionException` is used and is unchecked (i.e. is a `RuntimeException`), hence the catch/throw wrapping any exception into a `CompletionException`.

Also, as @WeGa indicated, you can use the [`handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to deal with exceptions potentially being thrown by the result:

```
CompletableFuture<T> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...);
future.handle((ex,res) -> {
        if (ex != null) {
            // An exception occurred ...
        } else {
            // No exception was thrown, 'res' is valid and can be handled here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Or, if you're using Callable<T> rather than Runnable, instead try supplyAsync: ```CompletableFuture<T> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(myCallable, myExecutor);```

Comment: `supplyAsync` receives a `Supplier`. The code will not compile if you attempt to pass in a `Callable`.

Comment: You can also implement exception handling with java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#handle, chained right after CompletableFuture: CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...).handle((response, throwable) -> ...)

Answer (score 15):

I published a little [futurity](https://github.com/Spikhalskiy/futurity) project that tries to do better than [the straightforward way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23302308/525203) in the answer.

The main idea is to use only one thread (and of course with not just a spin loop) to check all Futures states inside, which helps to avoid blocking a thread from a pool for each Future -> CompletableFuture transformation.

Usage example:

```
Future oldFuture = ...;
CompletableFuture profit = Futurity.shift(oldFuture);
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Is it using a timer thread ? How come this is not the accepted answer ?

Comment: @Kira Yeah, it basically uses one timer thread to wait on all submitted futures.

Answer (score 9):

Suggestion:

https://gabfssilva.github.io/old-java-future-to-completable-future/

But, basically:

```
public class CompletablePromiseContext {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public static void schedule(Runnable r) {
        SERVICE.schedule(r, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

And, the CompletablePromise:

```
public class CompletablePromise<V> extends CompletableFuture<V> {
    private Future<V> future;

    public CompletablePromise(Future<V> future) {
        this.future = future;
        CompletablePromiseContext.schedule(this::tryToComplete);
    }

    private void tryToComplete() {
        if (future.isDone()) {
            try {
                complete(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                completeExceptionally(e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                completeExceptionally(e.getCause());
            }
            return;
        }

        if (future.isCancelled()) {
            cancel(true);
            return;
        }

        CompletablePromiseContext.schedule(this::tryToComplete);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final Future<String> stringFuture = service.submit(() -> "success");
        final CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletablePromise<>(stringFuture);

        completableFuture.whenComplete((result, failure) -> {
            System.out.println(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is quite simple to reason about & elegant & fits most use cases. I would make the `CompletablePromiseContext ` not-static and take param for the check interval (which is set to 1 ms here) then overload the `CompletablePromise<V>` constructor to be able to provide your own `CompletablePromiseContext` with a possibly different (longer) check interval for long-running `Future<V>` where you don't have to absolutely be able to run callback (or compose) immediately upon finishing, and you can also have an instance of `CompletablePromiseContext` to watch a set of `Future` (in case you have many)

Answer (score 6):

Let me suggest another (hopefully, better) option:
https://github.com/vsilaev/java-async-await/tree/master/com.farata.lang.async.examples/src/main/java/com/farata/concurrent

Briefly, the idea is the following:

1. Introduce `CompletableTask<V>` interface -- the union of the
   `CompletionStage<V>` + `RunnableFuture<V>`
2. Warp `ExecutorService` to return `CompletableTask` from `submit(...)` methods (instead of `Future<V>`)
3. Done, we have runnable AND composable Futures.

Implementation uses an alternative CompletionStage implementation (pay attention, [CompletionStage](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/completion-stage) rather than CompletableFuture):

Usage:

```
J8ExecutorService exec = J8Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CompletionStage<String> = exec
   .submit( someCallableA )
   .thenCombineAsync( exec.submit(someCallableB), (a, b) -> a + " " + b)
   .thenCombine( exec.submit(someCallableC), (ab, b) -> ab + " " + c);
```

Comment: Small update: code is moved to separate project, https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent, and now it's possible to use out-of-the-way box Executor-s from java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> fromFuture(Future<T> f) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null).thenCompose(avoid -> {
        try {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(f.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e.getCause());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea goes like this:

```
Future<?> future = null;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(future::get);
```

However, you will receive some warnings from your compiler.

So, here is the first option.

```
Future<?> future = null;
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        ()->{
            try {
                return future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
```

Second Option, hide the try...catch via casting the functional interface.

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface MySupplier<T> extends Supplier<T> {
        @Override
        default T get() {
            try {
                return getInternal();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        T getInternal() throws Exception;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Future<?> future = null;
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync((MySupplier<?>) future::get);

    }
```

Third Option, find out some 3rd party lib which has provided such a functional interface.

See Also: [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception)