# Should API return CompletionStage or CompletableFuture

Tags: api, java-8, concurrent.futures, completable-future

When building an API it is a good practice to code to an interface so it seems like returning CompletionStage seems like a best approach. However I realized that I happen to be always calling .toCompletableFuture after getting the CompletionStage. What is the recommended approach in this case?

Comment: That depends on *why* you are always calling `toCompletableFuture()`…

Comment: @Holger Can you elaborate on that? We are calling toCompletableFuture so we can call methods which are only available in it. It does feel little confusing where we can get concrete instance from the interface. They are closely coupled and defeats the purpose of having an interface.

Comment: Well, `CompletionStage` defines 38 methods, the `Future` interface defines five more. If you permanently (“always”) find yourself needing the remaining eight, `CompletableFuture` specific methods, coding against an interface is indeed not for you.

Answer (score 8):

See my reply at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49158702/1113842

Like Holger asked, why do you call `toCompletableFuture`?

- Do you want to the caller to `complete`/`cancel` it? Most applications provide their own mechanisms for completing the stage. Thus, it's not necessary to expose these methods.
- Do you want to use the blocking `get`? This should be avoided in async programming.

If the answers are no to both questions, you should return `CompletionStage`.

Answer (score 3):

An API using the `CompletionStage` is meant for non-blocking use, so the call `.toCompletableFuture()` is only required if the caller does not work in non-blocking way.
If the API is not non-blocking, it should return plain old `Future` interface.

Comment: See also the question from the reverse perspective https://stackoverflow.com/q/34930840/1531945