# Convert CompletableFuture (Java 8) to Future (Scala)

Tags: scala, java-8

I want to change the return type of the method below to `Future[Unit]`

```
def send(data: Array[Byte]): CompletableFuture[Void] = {
  val f:CompletableFuture[Void] = client.send(data)
  f
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.12.1. Is there any convenient way to convert from Java 8 `CompletableFuture` to Scala's `Future`?

Comment: The first place I'd look is in scala-java8-compat.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, it's called [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat), and [here's the method you're looking for](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala#L77).

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use the method? I think that would be helpful

Comment: You just call it? `scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toScala(completionStage)`

Answer (score 24):

Though 2.12 was mentioned by asker (in 2017), now we have 2.13 and the conversion has become easier:

> Starting Scala 2.13, the standard library includes scala.jdk.FutureConverters which provides Java to Scala CompletableFuture/Future implicit conversions:

```
import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._

val scalaFuture = javaFuture.asScala
```

[Convert a Java Future to a Scala Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033290/convert-a-java-future-to-a-scala-future#answer-53939994)

Answer (score 1):

To convert a CompletableFuture to Scala's Future and get rid of the wrapping CompletionException:

```
package mycompany.common.concurrent

object Extensions {
  implicit class UnwrappedCompletableFuture[T](cf: CompletableFuture[T]) {

    import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._

    def toScala: Future[T] = {
      val f = cf.asScala
      f.recover {
        case ex: CompletionException if ex.getCause != null => throw ex.getCause
      }(ExecutionContext.global)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import mycompany.common.concurrent.Extensions._

val result = fetcher.fetchAsync().toScala.recover {
  case ex: YourActualException => 
}
```