# Create a kafka consumer using zookeeper in scala

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Trying to create a consumer in kafka using zookeeper but was not able to.But using bootstrap server consumer start listening.
Can anyone help if is it good idea to connect to broker directly without zookeeper.
If we want to connect using zookeeper, how that can be achieved.

```
val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.put("group.id","grp1")
    properties.put("key.deserialize", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
```

how can we connect to zookeeper.

Comment: clients don't talk to zookeper directly anymore. Bootstrap server (broker) is now the endpoint for both consumers and producers.

Comment: Scala kafka consumer have been removed in Kafka 2.0.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56180566/380250

Comment: thanks @aran, if clients don't talk to zookeeper directly than what will be role of zookeeper. kafka is distributed and it requires state management and zookeeper was trusted with this responsibility, if it is removed how this management is being achieved. It will be great if anyone help me understand.

Comment: Take a look here @shubham . Point 6 disappears, so the broker is the one with thar role now. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-role-of-Zookeeper-in-Kafka-What-benefits-will-I-miss-out-on-if-I-don%E2%80%99t-use-Zookeeper-and-Kafka-together/answer/Gwen-Shapira