# Why does it not recognize asScala method?

Tags: scala, akka, scala-java-interop

I have the following code, that does not compile:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.typed.Behavior
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.pattern.FutureRef
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.typed.scaladsl.ActorMaterializer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin._
import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._


import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration

object KafkaDetectorActor {

  val create: Behavior[NotUsed] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
    implicit val system = context.system
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val dispatcher = context.system.dispatchers


    Behaviors.same
  }

  private def health(server: String)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[Boolean] = {
    val props = new Properties
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server)
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "10000")
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "5000")

        AdminClient
          .create(props)
          .listTopics()
          .names()
          .asScala

  }
```

where [`names`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/ListTopicsResult.html#names--) returns `KafkaFuture[java.util.Set[String]]`.

It does not recognize `asScala` method. The `scala.jdk.FutureConverters._` library is imported. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It also does not work.@MarioGalic Did you try it?

Comment: Do you use scala 2.13?

Comment: what's the compilation error?

Comment: `value asScala is not a member of org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaFuture[java.util.Set[String]]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value asScala`?
[error]       .asScala
`

Comment: `AdminClient` is a Java library and the method `names()` return a Future.

Answer (score 3):

`scala.jdk.FutureConverters` [operate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429658/5205022) on `CompletableFuture` so try first [converting](https://gist.github.com/bmaggi/8e42a16a02f18d3bff9b0b742a75bfe7) `KafkaFuture` to `CompletableFuture` like so

```
  implicit class KafkaFutureToCompletableFuture[T](kafkaFuture: KafkaFuture[T]) {
    def toCompletableFuture: CompletableFuture[T] = {
      val wrappingFuture = new CompletableFuture[T]
      kafkaFuture.whenComplete((value, throwable) => {
        if (throwable != null) {
          wrappingFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable)
        }
        else {
          wrappingFuture.complete(value)
        }
      })
      wrappingFuture
    }
  }
```

Now we can call `toCompletableFuture.asScala`. For example,

```
import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._
KafkaFuture.completedFuture(42).toCompletableFuture.asScala.foreach(println)
```

outputs `42`. In your case, try

```
AdminClient
  .create(props)
  .listTopics()
  .names()
  .toCompletableFuture
  .asScala
```

Comment: Any reason not to define a conversion directly to a Scala `Future` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov) suggested, you could just convert directly to Scala's Future:

```
   implicit class KafkaFutureEx[T](kafkaFuture: KafkaFuture[T]) {
    val p = Promise[T]
    kafkaFuture.whenComplete { (value, throwable) =>
      {
        if (throwable != null) {
          p.failure(throwable)
        } else {
          p.success(value)
        }
      }
    }

    def toScalaFuture = p.future
  }
```