# What does "compose" mean in the context of concurrency?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locking, future

From Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott

> The fact that correctness depends on locking order means  that lock-based program fragments do not **compose**: we cannot take existing lock-based abstractions and safely call them from within a new critical section.

What does "compose" mean?

Why do lock-based program fragments do not compose?

From [Transform Java Future into a CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23301598/3284469)

> Java 8 introduces CompletableFuture, a new implementation of Future that is **composable** (includes a bunch of thenXxx methods). I'd like to use this exclusively, but many of the libraries I want to use return only **non-composable** Future instances.

What does it mean by some future instances are composable and some are not?

Thanks.

Comment: It means combining/arranging parts to create something new.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me how that is done in code, or point me to such examples?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, any lock-based thing is not trivial to compose.  At the very least, to avoid dead-locks, you must define a lock order and use it everywhere.    Also, a lock should be acquired for a really short time, so you should avoid locking around code that can block, such as long running operations or waiting on I/O.

For the second part, the `Future<V>` interface does not compose well because the only way to know when it finishes is through polling or blocking (`isDone()` and `get()`).  You have no other way to be notified of the `Future<V>`'s completion.

There are specific futures that compose easily, such as `CompletableFuture<V>`, which allows you to be notified instead of polling or blocking.

However, if you get one of these as a `Future<V>`, you won't be able to take advantage of its notification mechanism.  You can try casting to the `CompletionStage<V>` interface, which contains the composition methods.