# Hazelcast ScheduledExecutorService callback

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I have seen in hazelcast document that in case of normal IExecutorService we have option to submit ExecutionCallback along with task, to get callback when task is completed or failed.
How this kind of callback can be achieved in case of IScheduledExecutorService?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no callback style api for `IScheduledExecutorService` yet. Since `IScheduledExecutorService` is a relatively new feature, I guess, more advanced api will be added in future releases.

As a (*dirty*) workaround, you can convert returned `IScheduledFuture` to a `j.u.c.CompletableFuture` using another thread or executor, either with blocking or periodic polling.

Comment: @modogan. are you referring this kind of solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301598/transform-java-future-into-a-completablefuture

Comment: Yes, but I don't suggest it unless you really need to listen a callback.