# Convert Future to Mono

Tags: java, future, project-reactor, completable-future

I have legacy code which returns convert java.util.concurrent.Future, now I am supposed to wrap this method call in a layer which returns reactor publishers Mono or Flux. I believe approach to convert to either of them should be similar so what is the correct way to convert it to Mono.

Suppose for example I am getting Future from API and I need Mono

Comment: I am kind of beginner in this area so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: this is possible but requires a dedicated thread. That is, the main goal of using Mono/Flux, memory economy, would not be achieved anyway.

Comment: This is analogous to transforming a `Future` to a `CompleteableFuture` as described here - since a future has no concept of a "callback" when done, you have to block a thread. It's certainly not pretty, but alas there's no sensible way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301598/transform-java-future-into-a-completablefuture

Answer (score 0):

Given that getting the result from a `Future` is always going to be blocking, a possible solution would be move that computation to a blocking-friendly scheduler.

```
 Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {
            Future future = null;
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
 }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

You can verify that your code is effectively non-blocking by using  BlockHound https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound

Answer (score -4):

You can use `Future::get` as supplier in `Mono::fromSupplier`.
Like this, `Mono.fromSupplier(Future::get)`.

Comment: This won't work. `Future::get` throws checked exceptions, which can't be handled with a method reference. The simplest approach would be to supply a lambda with try/catch around the `get` call, 

`Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {  try { return future.get(); } catch(....) { ... } });`

Comment: @zshift Thats not always true. `Callable` allows checked exceptions.