# java8 how to convert Future<T> to CompleteableFuture<T>

Tags: java

I am using jetty websocket api , which returns future for most of its calls.

What is the simple and efficient method for converting Future to CompletableFuture using java8.

I have looked at below links:

1. https://github.com/Spikhalskiy/futurity --> it imports lot of other  libraries.
2. [Transform Java Future into a CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301598/transform-java-future-into-a-completablefuture)
   --> acceptable answer uses Future.get() and blocks until completed.

Comment: There are no updates from the options that you listed.