# Exception thrown from method called as parameter

Tags: java, exception

My function looks like:

```
void Foo() throws Exception {
...
}
```

I'm then calling this method in other method's parameter:

```
Bar( () -> Foo());
```

And Bar() looks like this:

```
void Bar(Runnable method) {
    try {
        method.run()
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Earlier I had Foo() throwing RuntimeException so it worked, but when i changed it to throw Exception compiler won't allow me to run my code indicating its uncaught exception. I have to use checked exception so going back to Runtime is not an option.

**SOLUTION**
based on this solution [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception) I have used try catch block in this call

```
Bar( () -> { try { Foo(); } catch (Exception e) { }; } );
```

Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Can you add some errormessages?

Comment: Eclipse at line when i try to call Bar( () -> Foo()); says its "Unhandled exception type Exception"

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret your question, as to why you have to use a checked Exception in the second case. (If this is not your question please edit it accordingly)

A `RuntimeException` is any `Exception` that can not be fixed at runtime (like a `NullPointerException`), so that's why the compiler doesn't complain when you don't catch it. You still can catch a `RuntimeException` though.

So when you change it to a normal `Exception` the compiler then thinks, that this is something you should catch every time, because it may be fixable at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but what can I do about that? Calling Bar( () -> Foo()); is now impossible unless I change Foo() to not throwing Exception?

Comment: It's not impossible, you just have to handle the Exception that it throws with a `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because [`Runnable.run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--) is not declared to `throw Exception`.