# How to use throws keyword in lambda expressions java 8?

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

```
AccountService accountServiceLambda = () -> {
    Account account = new Account();
    accountService.save(account); 
}
```

In the above lambda expression, how can I declare throws AccountServiceException like below ?

```
public void createAccount() throws AccountServiceException {
     Account account = new Account();
     accountService.save(account);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Comment: You don’t. The `interface AccountService` already does.