# Why can't checked exceptions in a java stream be thrown at method level?

Tags: java, java-stream, java.util.concurrent

I've been learning about concurrency and the streams `API` and came across this. The `offerLast()`method can throw `InterruptedException`, so I get that I must handle it. What I don't get is why can't I throw it at the method level by adding `throws Exception`?. As it is this `code` does not compile.

```
static BlockingDeque<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

public static void testing() throws Exception {
    IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i+1).limit(5)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(s -> queue.offerLast(s, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```

I know it can be solved by surrounding it in a `try/catch`, or by creating a `wrapper method` that handles the `error`, but I'm still trying to understand why it can't be thrown at the method level.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Comment: Because forEach() expects a Consumer instance. And the accept() method of Consumer can't throw any checked exception: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, for some reason I wasn't thinking of it as a Consumer. That makes sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because lambda expressions are not always evaluated immediately.

Let's you have this:

```
public Supplier<String> giveMeASupplier() throws Exception {
    return () -> someMethodThatThrowsCheckedException()
}
```

According to you, the above would work. Right?

Now in another method, I can do this:

```
Suppler<String> supplier = null;
try {
    supplier = giveMeASupplier() // no exception is thrown here.
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
if (supplier != null) {
    System.out.println(supplier.get()); // this might throw an exception! Yet it's not in a try...catch!
}
```

Now what do you think would happen if `supplier.get()` throws an exception? Is there anything to catch it? No. If somehow the `catch` block a few lines before gets run, then it would be *really* weird.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that the "method" you're referring to is `Consumer.accept`, not  `YourClass.testing`.

The lambda `s -> queue.offerLast(s, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` is an implementation of `java.util.function.Consumer.accept(T)`, which doesn't declare that it can throw `InterruptedException`.

And this behavior is not particular to streams, wherever a lambda expression is defined, it must comply with the signature of the abstract method of the functional interface it implements.