# Pass reference to method instead of value (or something like that) - JAVA

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

I have multiple objects with value stored in -

```
object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName(0)
```

It's possible, that list is empty so-

```
object.getList().get(0)
```

throws a NPE

I want to pass-

`object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName()`

to another method and handle the exception there.

For example:

```
// calling the method
myMethod(object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName());

public void myMethod(Object o){
    try {
        String name = o;
    }catch (Exception e){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that -

```
EvaluateLaterObject elo = new EvaluateLaterObject(object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName());
myMethod(elo);

public void myMethod(EvaluateLaterObject elo){
    try {
        String name = elo.getValue();
    }catch (Exception e){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a functional interface such as [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and a lambda

```
myMethod(() -> object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName());

public void myMethod(Supplier<String>){
    try {
        String name = elo.get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you want to support any exception, you'll need to define your own functional interface e.g.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowableSupplier<T>
{
    T get() throws Throwable;
}
```

Comment: Only works for unchecked (runtime) exceptions though.

Comment: @SME_Dev Right. Trivially avoided though.

Answer (score 1):

Either what already was given by Michael

```
Supplier<String> objectSupplier = () -> object.getList().get(0).getSomeObject.getName();

public void myMethod(Supplier<String> objectSupplier){
    try {
        String name = objectSupplier.get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Which does not really handle the exception.

Or use the optionality. Assuming the list items have class ListItem and getSomeObject is of class Item:

```
Optional<String> nameOpt = object.getList().stream()  // Stream<ListItem>
        .findFirst()                                  // Optional<ListItem>
        .map(ListItem::getSomeObject)                 // Optional<Item>
        .map(Item::getName);                          // Optional<String>

public void myMethod(Optional<String> nameOpt){
    nameOpt.ifPresent(name -> System.out.println(name));
    String nm = nameOpt.orElse("(No Name)");
}
```

Comment: Right. The correct approach here is to avoid the NPE in the first place.