# How to refactor methods that only differ in which method they call on an object in java?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

Probably kind of a beginner question but I am stuck in my box.

Assuming the following interface:

```java
public interface Foo {
    void one() throws Exception;
    void two() throws Exception;
}
```

And this class:

```java
class MyClass {
    private Collection<Foo> foos;

    MyClass(Collection<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public void oneOnAllFoos() {
        // assuming more code...
        for (Foo foo : foos) {
            // assuming more code...
            foo.one(); // the only different line
        }
    }

    public void twoOnAllFoos() {
        // assuming more code...
        for (Foo foo : foos) {
            // assuming more code...
            foo.two(); // the only different line
        }
    }
}
```

Now in case the `oneOnAllFoos` and `twoOnAllFoos` are the same except for the foo `one()` and `two()` calls, how can I refactor `MyClass` to get one method containing all logic letting me specify which method on the `Foo` objects to be called? I know it is possible using reflection but I think there must be a *KISS* way, too. Thanks!

**Edit:** added `throws Exception` to the interface methods.

**Edit2:** the `// assuming more code...` contains the exception handling of the interface method calls. There I collect the thrown exceptions to then throw them further as composite exception (must process all `Foo`s first.

Comment: I think you can use if-else inside for loop and call one(), two() accordingly.

Comment: @PriyankaW That isnt really helpful ... there are better ways to solve this, see the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface here:

```
private forEachFoo(Consumer<Foo> consumer) {
  for each foo: consumer.accept(foo) ...
```

to then pass in different consumers with simple lambdas, like:

```
public void oneOnAllFoos() {
  forEachFoo(f -> f.one());
```

or, as suggested in the other answer, by using a method reference `Foo::one`.

Edit: when your methods throw checked exceptions, you can do two use your own Consumer/Function interface see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a `Consumer` but actually forgot to add one important part which is that the interface methods can throw exceptions (see edit). This results in an error stating that there is an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in a `ThrowingConsumer<Foo>`:

```
interface ThrowingConsumer<T> {
    void accept(T t) throws Exception; // signature very similar to a normal Consumer
}

public void onAllFoos(ThrowingConsumer<Foo> consumer) {
    // assuming more code...
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        // assuming more code...
        consumer.accept(foo); // handle exception here.
    }
}
```

Callable via

```
onAllFoos(Foo::one);
```

Comment: You came in second, but you had the method reference ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a `Consumer` but actually forgot to add one important part which is that the interface methods can throw exceptions (see edit). This results in an error stating that there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: @Phil then you need to create a new interface of your own, called e.g. `ThrowingConsumer` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the best way to deal with your problem (in Java 8 at least) is to create a private method that takes a `Consumer<Foo>` as a parameter, such as:

```java
class MyClass {
    private Collection<Foo> foos;

    MyClass(Collection<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public void oneOnAllFoos() {
        abstractOnAllFoos(Foo::one);
    }

    public void twoOnAllFoos() {
        abstractOnAllFoos(Foo::two);
    }

    private void abstractOnAllFoos(Consumer<Foo> fooConsumer) {
        // assuming more code...
        for (Foo foo : foos) {
            // assuming more code...
            fooConsumer.accept(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

The choice of using a `consumer` has been made only because your methods `one()` and `two()` aren't returning anything.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a `Consumer` but actually forgot to add one important part which is that the interface methods can throw exceptions (see edit). This results in an error stating that there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: Unfortunately. you reached usages' limits with checked exception and consumers