# Handle checked exception in lambda

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I have some code that throws a checked exception. I want to call that code within a lambda in order to create a map from another map:

```
Map<String, Coordinate> map = getMap();
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> doSomething(x.getValue)));
```

where `doSometing` is the code that throws the exception:

```
int doSomething(Coordinate c) throws MyException { ... }
```

Now compiler surely complains about the exception not being handled. So I surround it with a `try-catch`, which looks pretty ugly:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> {
        try {
            return doSomething(x.getValue());
        } catch (MyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // return some error-code here???
        }
    }));
```

which also does not compile as we need to return something in the `catch`-case. However there´s not much sense in returning anything here in this exceptional case, which is why I actually do not want to handle the exception at that level. Can´t I just handle the exception in my calling code, where I create the lambda? So to say just one level above?

```
try {
    Map<String, Integer> result = ...
} catch (MyException e) { ... }
```

But that does not compile because the exception thrown from the lambda is not handled.

Comment: The question here would be, why would you want to use checked exception. Also, I believe that the standard way of handling checked exceptions in labdas (if you cannot just make it runtime) is to catch it inside lamda and rethrow an unchecked exception - you can use checked one as cause.

Comment: @Worthless Unfortunately `doSomething` is a 3rd-party-API that just throws.

Comment: Then yea, rethrowing is probably the easiest way to handle it.

Comment: @Worthless But how to do that in a nice way? Isn´t it possible to just let the exception bubble through the layers until it finally **is** handled?

Comment: Checked exceptions can't bubble through until it is handled. Each intervening method has to declare it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Baeldung's blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions): you could define consumer which can throw `Exception`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Exception> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;
}
```

and a static wrapper to map **checked exception** to `RuntimeException`:

```
static <T> Consumer<T> throwingConsumerWrapper(
  ThrowingConsumer<T, Exception> throwingConsumer) {

    return i -> {
        try {
            throwingConsumer.accept(i);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(
        throwingConsumerWrapper(toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> doSomething(x.getValue)))
    );
```

Comment: I already found this, but I coudn´t get the `toMap` working, because I just wrapped the `x -> doSomething`-part. Thatnks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all it's worth to filter your values. In case if you have values which can raise an exception.

Then you can use one of the popular wrappers (i.e. [jooq.lambda](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.12/org/jooq/lambda/fi/util/function/CheckedFunction.html)) or write your own

```
 map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> makeSureNoExtection(x))
    .collect(toMap(x -> x.getKey(), unchecked(x -> doSomething(x.getValue))));
```