# Why must I catch exceptions when providing lambda argument?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

Consider the following example:

```
public class LambdaArgsTest {
    private static void display(Supplier<?> arg) {
        try {
            // this is the place where the Exception("wrong") might be thrown
            // and it is in fact handled
            System.out.println(arg.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display(() -> {
            if(/*some condition*/) {
                // this statement will be rejected due to unhandled exception
                throw new Exception("wrong");
            }
            return "abcde";
        });
    }
}
```

Here comes the question: the lambda argument in the above example is an object that'll be executed later inside the "display()" method. It is obviously not executed when passing the arguments to the "display()".

Why is it rejected by the compiler? I think it's quite reasonable to surround it by try...catch only when the lambda is actually called.

Comment: Because checked exceptions need to be declared or caught, and you do neither. It doesn't matter when they might be thrown.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Comment: If you change the `Supplier` to `Callable` which does throw an expectation it will compile just fine.

Comment: It is not uncommon to add a `ThrowingSupplier` such as the one I wrote for this purpose. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle-core/latest/net/openhft/chronicle/core/util/ThrowingSupplier.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the signature of `Supplier` functional interface:

```
T get();
```

As you see, the method `get` is not declared to throw `Exception` (neither any other *checked*  exception).

In Java, there are *checked* vs *unchecked* exceptions (unchecked exceptions are those which inherit from `RuntimeException`). Checked exceptions must be handled, either by catching them in a `catch` block, or by declaring that the method `throws` that exception.

If the signature of `Supplier.get` were:

```
T get() throws Exception:
```

The code would compile fine.

Try throwing `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception` and the code will compile fine.

---

**EDIT:** As per Peter Lawrey's suggestion in the comments, if you do need to throw a checked exception from within your lambda expression, you could use e.g. [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), whose only one method's signature is as follows:

```
T call() throws Exception;
```

You'd just need to pass a `Callable` to your `display` method instead of a `Supplier`.

Comment: e.g. `Callable` does throw an `Exception`

Comment: Hi @Peter, thanks for the suggestion, I will include an example with `Callable`