# Check if value is present in Map and return keys or throw exception

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java 8 stream to check if all the distinct characters in a string are present in a map and to return their keys as a List. I am able to do it using Stream like below:

```
...
map.put("Apple",'a');
map.put("Ball",'b');
map.put("Cat",'c');
map.put("Doll",'d');

String format = "aabbbc";

List<String> list = format.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).distinct()
                        .map(c -> map.entrySet().stream()
                                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c).findFirst().get().getKey())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So this returns me `["Apple","Ball","Cat"]`. However, I would have an input where the character might not be in the map. For example: `format = "aabbbczzzzz"`

In this case, I want to throw an exception saying that the Character is not found in the map. So I did this

```java
List<String> list = format.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
    .distinct()
    .map(c -> map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Character not found in Map")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But Java doesn't let me compile. Please help me with how to handle my requirement.

https://ideone.com/Kb2WoN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda expression you pass to the `map` is a `Function` which doesn't let you throw a checked exception. The contract of a `Functions` is:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
     R apply(T t);
}
```

It takes a value of type `T` and returns a value of type `R`. You cannot throw a checked exception from an implementation of `apply`.

You can change your code to throw an unchecked exception.

Also, you are missing a `map` call to map to the map key as stated in the other answer

```
List<String> list = format.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).distinct()
              .map(c -> map.entrySet().stream()
                      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c)
                      .map(Map.Entry::getKey) //extract the map key
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Character not found in Map"))) 
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also create a custom domain exception that extends RuntimeException and throw that.

References:

[Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception)

[Throwing checked exceptions in streams from Java Dev Central](https://javadevcentral.com/throw-checked-exceptions-in-java-streams)

---

Sidenote: You are looping through the map for each character in the string. To improve performance, you can create a reverse map so that you can look up (`O(1)`) if the character is present in the map and return the value.

Comment: Can you please post an example.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a reverse map but I did not want to create a new map since this lookup will be used in my application only once.

Comment: I have a question, - why won't the second .map throw an exception if the character is not found in the map ? since we are directly using method references to get the key from the entry.

Comment: No. If the character is not in the map the `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` won't be executed since nothing will pass the `filter` step.

Comment: Got it. So the `map` will not be executed and then the `findFirst` is going to be an `Optional` of nothing and hence throws the exception ?

Comment: Yes. Correct. It will be an *empty* Optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = format.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).distinct()
                .map(c -> {
                    Optional<Map.Entry<String, Character>> first = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c).findFirst();
                    if (first.isPresent()) {
                        return first.get().getKey();
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Character not found in Map");
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This should resolve your problem.
Reason why you were getting compile error is when you write the following line

```
.filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c).findFirst().orElseThrow(()-> new Exception("Character not found in Map"))).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You are collecting result in `List<Map.Entry<String, Character>>`. But in the reference variable you have used `List<String> list` which is the issue.
Also, you are throwing a **Checked Exception** which you have not handled explicitly. Better to use an **UnChecked Exception** like **RuntimeException.class**

The above answer could've been written in complete functional style in following way

```
List<String> list = format.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).distinct()
                .map(c -> map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c)
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `if (first.isPresent()) { return first.get().getKey();` This is not the way to write this in a functional style. Use `orElseThrow()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should throw `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception` or you should catch that in your lambda expression.

Second of all after using `findFirst`, you'll get an `Optional<Entry>` object, which means that you should map your result form `findFirst` to `Map.Entry::getKey`:

```
List<String> list = format.chars()
      .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
      .distinct()
      .map(c -> map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == c)
          .findFirst()
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Character not found in Map")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the Optional from findFirst() can be passed to the map function ?

Comment: @v1shnu can you explain what are you trying to achieve? it's vague for me. doesn't this code snippet do what you're after?