# Dynamically choose bean without Qualifier annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have a service that gets an URL from the user input, extracts the body content of this URL, apply CSS, and finally returns the result as a stream.

The tricky part is that I have different implementations depending on the URL, if the URL is not recognized, then a "default" implementation is used.
To do so, I used a BeanFactory to choose the correct implementation on Runtime.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("defaultHtmlToHtmlService")
public class DefaultHtmlToHtmlImpl implements HtmlToHtmlService {

    @Override
    public InputStream htmlToHtml(String url) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element content = document.body();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(content.outerHtml().getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    }
}

@Component
public class BeanFactory {


private final HtmlToHtmlService defaultHtmlToHtmlService;

private final HtmlToHtmlService impl1;

private final HtmlToHtmlService impl2;

@Autowired
public BeanFactory(@Qualifier("defaultHtmlToHtmlImpl") HtmlToHtmlService defaultHtmlToHtmlService,
                   @Qualifier("impl1") HtmlToHtmlService impl1,
                   @Qualifier("impl2") HtmlToHtmlService impl2) {
    this.defaultHtmlToHtmlService = defaultHtmlToHtmlService;
    this.impl1 = impl1;
    this.impl2 = impl2;
}

public HtmlToHtmlService getHtmlToHtmlImpl(String url) {
    if (url.contains("some pattern")) {
        return impl1;
    } else if (url.contains("some other pattern")) {
        return impl2;
    } else {
        return defaultHtmlToHtmlService;
    }
}
```

This is working just fine. However, my issue is that I don't want my BeanFactory to share any information with the rest, but I do not know how to decouple it. Basically, I want to remove the `@Qualifier` annotation, and not to have to manually enter the new URL patterns in the Bean Factory in the future when I will get more implementations.

I saw that maybe `@PostConstruct` annotation or using static blocks could be the solution, but I am really not sure how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can help in this case. If you define a `List<HtmlToHtmlService>` in the constructor of the component in question, Spring can populate it with all implementations available in the context (you may want to rename the class `BeanFactory` to avoid ambiguity with Spring's own `BeanFactory`):

```
@Component
public class HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory {

    private final List<HtmlToHtmlService> services;

    @Autowired
    public HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory(List<HtmlToHtmlService> services) {
        this.services = services
    }

    public HtmlToHtmlService getHtmlToHtmlImpl(String url) {
        return services.stream()
            .filter(service -> service.supportsUrl(url))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("No service found that supports [%s]", url)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I have to surround the lambda expression with try and catch, and therefore return a boolean... Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception ?

Comment: The exception is not the issue, but the return type. I get 'Bad return type in lambda expression: InputStream cannot be converted to boolean'

Comment: @LaChope The lambda that is specified in the `filter` method is supposed to return a boolean because the filter will test a condition. It should not return an InputStream. In the code i've shown, once the method `getHtmlToHtmlImpl` returns a `HtmlToHtmlService`, you can call on it the method that processes the url and returns InputStream. If this doesn't help, you may want to edit the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed, I did not see it like this. Sorry about that, I have very little knowledge about lambdas... Your answer solved my issue, thank you.