# Throw exception by condition in stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How to filter stream expression to throw exception?

I have function to check sum of list elements, if sum is more than 1 -> throw exception

```java
Double sum = list.stream().map(element::getNumber).reduce(0.0,Double::sum);
if(sum>1){
   throw new Exception("message);
}
```

Is it possible to add `if` condition to stream expression to get rid of the additional `if` condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of the single argument `Stream.reduce()` and `Optional.orElseThrow()`

```java
list.stream()
    .map(element::getNumber)
    .reduce(Double::sum)
    .filter(sum -> sum <= 1)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("message"));
```

Comment: A nice one. I wondered if there is a solution using `mapToDouble`... but nope.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inside of the `reduce` operation, the downside is that you can't use a checked exception natively, but you can find [workarounds to still throw a checked exception inside of a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198349/5050667)

```
Double sum = list.stream()
                 .map(element::getNumber)
                 .reduce(0.0, (first, second) -> {
                     double s = first + second;
                     if (s > 1) throw new RuntimeException("");
                     return s;
                 });
```