# Is it possible to pass on an exeption thrown during a stream operation?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, checked-exceptions

Consider the following java code:

```java
    public void write(FrameConsumer fc) throws FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception{
        frameStream.forEach(n -> fc.consume(n));        
    }
```

In this case "frameStream" is a Stream of Objects that can be passed to the "consume" method, and fc is a class containing the "consume" method. Another important note is that the "consume" method throws a "FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception", which I would like to pass on to whatever method calls "write" in the future.

However the above code does not compile, because: "Unhandled exception type FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception Java(16777384)". Why is that?

Best regards,
CCI

EDIT:
Puting a try_catch block inside the lambda expression does not solve the problem either, hence:

```java
public void write(FrameConsumer fc) throws FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception{
    frameStream.forEach(n -> {
        try {
            fc.consume(n);
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            throw e;   //**this part does not compile**
        }
    });
}
```

(As provided by @Soumya Manna) does not compile either. The compiler still wants for the program to handle the "FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e" as it is thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception)

Comment: As suggested twice now, a way to do this would be to throw a runtime and not a checked exeption. This does indeed work! It does not however answer the question of why the code will not compile, which is what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the lambda can't throw a checked exception is that [`java.lang.Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)'s parameter (`action`) is of type [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), whose only non-`default` method, `accept`, does not declare any exceptions.

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in lambda. You may simple write for loop and throw it or use try-catch block in lambda and throw Runtime exception there.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the exception in a `RuntimeException` and then unwrap it:

```
public class ExceptionWrapper extends RuntimeException {
    public ExceptionWrapper(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

// ...

    public void write(FrameConsumer fc) throws FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception {
        try {
            frameStream.forEach(n -> {
                try {
                    fc.consume(n));
                } catch(FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    throw new ExceptionWrapper(e);
                }
            });
        } catch(ExceptionWrapper e) {
            throw (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception) e.getCause();
        }
    }
```