# Looking for Built-in Function in Java8 to ignore Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

I have an integration test where one of the methods I am calling *sometimes* throws an exception.  I would like to ignore the exception but I would like to do it in the most elegant way possible.

Initially I was doing this like this:

```
// GIVEN
NewsPaper newspaper = new NewsPaper();
Coffee coffee = new Coffee();

// WHEN
try{
    coffee.spill()
}catch(Exception e){
    // Ignore this exception.  I don't care what coffee.spill 
    // does as long as it doesn't corrupt my newspaper
}

// THEN
Assert.assertTrue(newspaper.isReadable);
```

While browsing stackoverflow, I noticed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659553/251589) that I could rewrite my code like this:

```
// GIVEN
NewsPaper newspaper = new NewsPaper();
Coffee coffee = new Coffee();

// WHEN
ingoreExceptions(() -> coffee.spill());


// THEN
Assert.assertTrue(newspaper.isReadable);
```

However, I need to provide my own implementation of {{ignoringExc}}:

```
public static void ingoreExceptions(RunnableExc r) {
  try { r.run(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}

@FunctionalInterface public interface RunnableExc { void run() throws Exception; }
```

Questions:

- Does Java8 ship with something like this that I can use out of the box?
- What utility libraries have something like this?

This seems like a general enough piece of code that I should be able to use someone else's.  Don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's a couple of lines and in almost all cases, a terrible idea. So I don't think there's a JDK-built-in exception swallower. Various testing harnesses often provide something, though.

Comment: @pvg The interface is useful, but I agree that the method is unlikely to be included in any library other than one made for unit testing.

Comment: Yeah and even in those cases, the utilities that help you skip the exception handling will generally log them in some way. Non-local exits have implications about your code coverage, for instance, if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: JUnit and TestNG have ways to expect exceptions, but that's a little different in that the test fails if you don't get the exception.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way using builtin features, I can come up with is

```
new FutureTask<>(() -> coffee.spill()).run();
```

The `FutureTask` doesn’t ignore exceptions, but catches and records them, so it’s still your decision not to query the result.

If `spill()` has been declared `void`, it can’t be used as `Callable` that simple, so you would have to use

```
new FutureTask<>(() -> { coffee.spill(); return null; }).run();
```

But it’s debatable, whether any lambda expression based solution can be a *simplification* of your original code, which only looks less concise due to linebreaks:

```
try{ coffee.spill(); } catch(Exception e){}
ignoreExceptions(() -> coffee.spill());// saved four chars...
```