# Java in-one-line exception handling with true/false result

Tags: java, syntax

```
boolean pingOK = false;
try {
  pingOK = InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(200);
} catch(IOException e) {
  pingOK = false;
}
```

Can these code cut down from 6 lines to 1 line?

Such as:

```
boolean pingOK = withNoException(InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(200));
```

Maybe above Java 8 some functional exception trick?

Or under Java 7 is there some way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659462/how-to-ignore-exceptions-in-java

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own helper to do that:

```
static <T> T withNoException(Supplier<? extends T> supplier, T defaultValue) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

...

boolean pingOK = withNoException(() -> InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(200), false);
```

Comment: This is neat code, but please OP look at the question that jspcal linked to, esspecially these parts: "You should **never** ignore exceptions." and "I would gravely doubt the sanity of any testing code"  Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659462/how-to-ignore-exceptions-in-java