# Throwing exception from lambda

Tags: java, error-handling, lambda, java-8, checked-exceptions

Given this java 8 code

```
public Server send(String message) {
    sessions.parallelStream()
        .map(Session::getBasicRemote)
        .forEach(basic -> {
          try {
            basic.sendText(message);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        });

    return this;
}
```

how do we properly make this `IOException` be delegated up the stack of the method call? (in nutshell how to make this method throw this `IOException` ?)

Lambdas in java does not look very friendly to error handling...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My approach would be to *sneakily* throw it from the lambda, but take care to have the `send` method declare it in its `throws` clause. Using the `Exceptional` class [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270760/1103872):

```
public Server send(String message) throws IOException {
  sessions.parallelStream()
          .map(Session::getBasicRemote)
          .forEach(basic -> Exceptional.from(() -> basic.sendText(message)).get());
  return this;
}
```

This way you're effectively making the compiler "look away" for just a bit, disabling its exception checking at one spot in your code, but by declaring the exception on your `send` method, you restore the regular behavior for all its callers.

Comment: Oh now I like that. That is indeed very sneaky.

Answer (score 6):

I [wrote an extension](https://github.com/JeffreyFalgout/ThrowingStream) to the Stream API which allows for checked exceptions to be thrown.

```
public Server send(String message) throws IOException {
    ThrowingStream.of(sessions, IOException.class)
        .parallelStream()
        .map(Session::getBasicRemote)
        .forEach(basic -> basic.sendText(message));

    return this;
}
```

Comment: thanks, now this is really nice interface :) will definitely check out your source code

Answer (score 3):

The problem is indeed that all `@FunctionalInterface`s used in lambdas do not allow exceptions to be thrown, save for unchecked exceptions.

One solution is using [a package of mine](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas); with it, your code can read:

```
sessions.parallelStream()
    .map(Session::getBasicRemote)
    .forEach(Throwing.consumer(basic -> basic.sendText(message)));
return this;
```

Comment: How does that let `send` throw the exception?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I understand that. But a **lot** more work is required to then make `send` throw the `IOException`. If I'm not mistaken, you basically have to catch the `ThrownByLambdaException`, and then have a series of `instanceof` to figure out what the actual exception was so you can rethrow it. Maybe not that bad for one or two exceptions, but still pretty verbose.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To stay fair to our colleague fge (and as you discovered in our chat), `throwing-lambdas` does support the sneaky throwing idiom.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Although as far as I can tell, the above doesn't actually use it, nor was it explained (e.g., that if it does use a sneaky throw, the `throws` decl. on `send` is essential and the compiler won't force you to add it).