# Make a Stream into an Iterable?

Tags: java, java-stream, iterable

[`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) inherits an [iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator()) method to produce an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html).

But I need an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) rather than an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html).

For example, given this string:

```
String input = "this\n" +
        "that\n" +
        "the_other";
```

…I need to pass those parts of string as an `Iterable` to a specific library. Calling `input.lines()` yields a `Stream`. So I would be set if I could make that `Stream` into a `Iterable` of its elements.

Comment: @Naman Related, but that appears to be the reverse of what Basil is doing in this Q&A.

Comment: Another way to get an Iterable would just be to collect to a List.

Comment: This question is different from the "duplicate". I was looking for THIS question, not the other. Thanks @Holger, for the answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As explained in [Why does Stream<T> not implement Iterable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20129762/2711488), an `Iterable` bears the expectation to be able to provide an `Iterator` more than once, which a `Stream` can’t fulfill. So while you can create an `Iterable` out of a `Stream` for an ad-hoc use, you have to be careful about whether attempts to iterate it multiple times could exist.

Since you said, “*I need to pass those parts of string as an `Iterable` to a specific library*”, there is no general solution as the code using the `Iterable` is outside your control.

But if you are the one who creates the stream, it is possible to create a valid `Iterable` which will simply repeat the stream construction every time an `Iterator` is requested:

```
Iterable<String> lines = () -> "this\nthat\nthe_other".lines().iterator();
```

This fulfills the expectation of supporting an arbitrary number of iterations, while not consuming more resources than a single stream when being traversed only once.

```
for(var s: lines) System.out.println(s);
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println(String.join("\n", lines));
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. It might be worth adding (as a slightly more advanced addendum) that while it is possible to say `Iterable<String> lines = "this\nthat\nthe_other".lines()::iterator;` this is one of those rare cases where a method reference is not the same as a lambda and in fact would have undesired effect.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou method references of the form `expression::name` are never the same as a lambda expressions, not even for `System.out::println`. But here, we have one of the cases where it matters

Comment: In this case, lines would be getting called every time, but I don't see the difference between between a method and  a lambda if `Stream<String> lines = str.lines();` then you create the `Iterable<String> iter = lines::iterator` versus `()->lines.iterator()`.

Comment: @matt nobody said that there was a difference between `stream::iterator` and `() -> stream.iterator()`. In fact, my answer precisely said, there there is *no general solution* for converting an existing stream to a valid iterable that allows multiple iterations. Repeating the stream construction every time an iterator is requested, i.e. here it means calling `lines()` every time, is what makes the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant in your comment where you said "expression::name" is never the same as a lambda expression. I think your answer is good.

Comment: @matt well, formally, it isn’t the same. `expression::name` means “*evaluate `expression` once and capture the result*”, whereas `() -> expression.name(…)` means “*evaluate `expression` each time the function body is evaluated*”. The differences are tiny when “`expression`” is just a local variable, but even then, it’s different, i.e. `stream::iterator` will behave different than `() -> stream.iterator()` when `stream` is `null`. So my statement still holds, `expression::name` is always different to a lambda expression, the question is, how much does it matter for my specific use case.

Comment: If you had a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` then you could create an `Iterable<T>` from that, but I think the use would be niche.

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

**Just cast**, no need to convert.

Cast `Stream<String>::iterator` to `Iterable<String>`.

## Details

**CAUTION** See [Answer by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873914/642706) explaining dangers of using a stream-backed `Iterable`.

Yes, you can make an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) from a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

The solution is simple, but not obvious. See [this post](http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-do-i-turn-a-stream-into-an-iterable/) on [*Maurice Naftalin's Lambda FAQ*](http://www.lambdafaq.org/).

The signature of the [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator()) method of [`BaseStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html) (superclass of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)) returning a [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) matches the only method of the functional interface [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html), so the method reference `Stream<T>::iterator` can be used as an instance of `Iterable<T>`. (The fact that both methods have the same name is coincidental.)

Make your input.

```
String input = "this\n" +
        "that\n" +
        "the_other";
Stream<String> stream = input.lines() ;
```

Use the method reference to generate a `Iterable<String>`.

```
Iterable< String > iterable = stream::iterator;
```

Test the results.

```
for ( String s : iterable ) 
{
    System.out.println( "s = " + s );
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/66zqAD).

> s = this

> s = that

> s = the_other

**CAVEAT** Beware of the risk of stream-backed `Iterable`. Explained in the correct [Answer by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873914/642706).

Comment: Technically, you aren't casting from `Stream<String>` because `stream::iterator` isn't of type `Stream<String>`.

Comment: I'm not sure casting is the right terminology. You're _creating_ an instance of `Iterable` through a method reference; the `(Iterable<String>)` just tells the compiler which functional interface is the target.

Comment: @Slaw & @kaya3 These subtleties have escaped my understanding. I do not see how `(Iterable<String>)` is anything but a cast, yet I certainly do not understand the situation, as your comments prompted me to put an extra set of parens around `( (Iterable<String>) stream )` which causes the code to fail – proving my understanding is flawed. So please do edit my Answer to clarify, or post your own Answer with a better explanation.

Comment: @Slaw the problem is, it is correct that there is a cast, but it is not correct to say that the cast is the solution. The solution consists of a method reference and a cast. The cast could be replaced by another construct providing the intended target type, e.g. passing the method reference to a method expecting an iterable or assigning it to a variable of type iterable. But the solution still requires a method reference or lambda expression for the conversion. So it’s nonsense to say “*just cast, rather than convert*” when there’s still a conversion (adapter code) *and* a cast.

Comment: Iterable is effectively a functional interface, you're creating an Iterable with the iterator method overridden by stream.iterator. It would effectively be `(Iterable<String>)()->stream.iterator()` or even more explicitly `new Iterable<String>(){ public Iterator<String> iterator(){ return stream.iterator();}`. So you are not casting a Stream to Iterable, which would fail.

Comment: @matt I am sorry that my example using a `for` loop confused matters. The goal of the Question is to get an `Iterable`. To that end, one does indeed cast without convert. My call to `Iterable::iterator` was a distraction, here just to demonstrate the results as output to the console. I have now broken up my code shown in this Answer to be more explicit about the solution being: cast stream to get an `Iterable`. I also added a caveat to point the reader to the very important  Answer by Holger.

Comment: Doesn't work. `(Iterator<String>)"one\ntwo".lines();` produces. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head cannot be cast to class java.util.Iterator` thats from openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14. Your code compiles but throws an exception. I don't know what you're actually running.

Comment: Your example is different that the code you pasted! You are **still using ::iterator** which is a method reference. The code you pasted with a literal cast is broken.

Comment: Edited the answer to use `::iterator`. Just casting the `Stream` itself doesn't work.