# Java compiler complaining about unreported IOException

Tags: java, file-io, exception, java-8, ioexception

I'm trying to write a method that lists all non-hidden files in a directory. However, when I add the condition `!Files.isHidden(filePath)` my code won't compile, and the compiler returns the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception 
java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I tried to catch the `IOException`, but the compiler still refuses to compile my code. Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm missing? Code is listed below.

```
try {    
    Files.walk(Paths.get(root)).forEach(filePath -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath) && !Files.isHidden(filePath)) {
            System.out.println(filePath);            
        } });
} catch(IOException ex) {    
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
} catch(Exception ex) {   
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: *@the compiler still refuses to compile my code"* - with the same error or a different one?

Comment: @mikej With the same error

Comment: You may try the approach outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270759/a-better-approach-to-handling-exceptions-in-a-functional-way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda expression passed to [`Iterable#forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) isn't allowed to throw an exception, so you need to handle it there:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(root)).forEach(filePath -> {
    try {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath) && !Files.isHidden(filePath)) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Or something more intelligent
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that in general lambda expression is *allowed* to throw an exception. It's not allowed in particular functional interface which is used here.

Comment: @TagirValeev I thought that using "The" instead of "A" in my answer conveyed that notion, but upon re-reading it I agree the point was not made clearly enough. I edited the text to clarify that point. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Well probably that's my problem. In my native language there are no articles, so sometimes I just don't notice the additional meaning they add to the sentence. Nevertheless the clarification is good.

Answer (score 4):

`isHiddenFile()` throws an IOException, and you're not catching it. Indeed, `forEach()` takes a Consumer as argument, and `Consumer.accept()` can't throw any checked exception. So you need to catch the exception *inside* by the lambda expression passed to `forEach()`:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(root)).forEach(filePath -> {
    try {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath) && !Files.isHidden(filePath)) {
            System.out.println(filePath);            
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         // do something here
    }
});
```