# Java8 Optional ignore NumberFormatException

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am converting a `Optional<String>` to `Integer` by `.map(Integer::parseInt)`. Is there a way to avoid `NumberFormatException` if string can't be parsed as `int`?

I want to avoid `try/catch` statement for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31270759/758280

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Guava [`Ints.tryParse`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29)

```
map(Ints::tryParse)
```