# Is Java's checked exception handling broken?

Tags: java, exception

From javaDocs on `java.lang.Exception` class:

> Checked exceptions need to be declared in a method or constructor's
>   throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or
>   constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

But consider this code:

```
package other;

public class CheckedExceptionHandling {

    private static <E extends Exception> void throwException() throws E {
        throw (E) new CheckedException2(); // unchecked cast warning
    }

    private static void setUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
            System.out.println("Unhandled exception: " + e.getClass()); // reports CheckedExceptionHandling$CheckedException2
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) /* no checked exceptions declared! */ {
        setUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        try {
            CheckedExceptionHandling.<CheckedException1>throwException();
        } catch (CheckedException1 e) {
            System.out.println(e); // never gets here
        }
    }
    // checked exceptions:
    public static class CheckedException1 extends Exception {}
    public static class CheckedException2 extends Exception {}

}
```

It compiles with a warning and the run-time result is:

> Unhandled exception: class other.CheckedExceptionHandling$CheckedException2

I expected a compile-time error `unreported exception CheckedException2;  must be caught or declared to be thrown` or `incompatible types: CheckedException2 cannot be converted to CheckedException1` or at least a `ClassCastException` at run time.
But the *compiler allows a checked exception to be left unhandled, undeclared and propagate outside the method `main` to the uncaught exception handler*.
Why? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Plus one. Nice well-written question. Java exception handling is broken. Eventually you'll get used to that and chill out.

Comment: There is nothing broken here. It is all according to spec.

Comment: This looks a lot like the "sneaky throw". Search for the term on your search engine of choice, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2x41h4/sneaky_exceptions_in_java/

Comment: The compiler clearly warned you that you are doing an _unchecked cast_. What is broken is not Java's exception handling, but your program. Just kidding,  Java's checked exceptions are a giant ball of mud.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038649/java-sneakythrow-of-exceptions-type-erasure

Comment: @Yuri You're casting your `CheckedException2` to a `CheckedException1` ,  your `throwException()` says it throws a `CheckedException1` and your code also catches a `CheckedException1` - so that wouldn't be a compiletime error . However the cast `(E) new CheckedException2()`  where your E is `CheckedException1` has some severe implications when using generics, described in the link Tunaki provided

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler does not look past method bounds. Within throwsException(), there is no info about E other than "extends Exception", so the Compiler can not proof that the cast is wrong and gives a warning, not an error (as Marko already pointed out in the comments).

Within main(), the compiler sees only the signature of "throwsException", which is defined as "throws E" and in main(), E is CheckedException. As CheckedException is catched, everything is fine here.

Then, Java throws away all generic type info at compile time, so the cast to E is not present in the byte code. Thereby, the runtime can not detect the type error either.

What is broken here is not the exception handling, but the type system.