# How does trick with rethrow checked exceptions works from the point of view of Java language?

Tags: java, generics, exception, java-stream, checked-exceptions

I have encountered that I must catch all checked exceptions inside stream expresions. 
I have read very popular topic:

[How can I throw CHECKED exceptions from inside Java 8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27644392/2674303)
And there is answer which suugest following approach:
we have 3 strings:
`"java.lang.Object"`
`"java.lang.Integer"` 
`"java.lang.Strin"`

We want to load classes by name.
Thus we need to use `Class#forName` method
[Class#forName java doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

As you can see following method declaration contains

```
throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Thus if we use usual loop we need to write followig code:

```
public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String arr[] = new String[]{"java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.Strin"};
    for(String className:arr){
        Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```

lets  try to rewrite it using streams:

```
 public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String arr[] = new String[]{"java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.Strin"};
        Stream.of(arr).forEach(Class::forName);
    }
```

compiler says that:

```
Error:(46, 32) java: incompatible thrown types java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in method reference
```

Ok, lets try to use approach from topic mentioned above:

we create following methods:

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> rethrowConsumer(Consumer_WithExceptions<T, E> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            consumer.accept(t);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throwAsUnchecked(exception);
        }
    };
}
```

---

```
 @FunctionalInterface
 public interface Consumer_WithExceptions<T, E extends Exception> {
     void accept(T t) throws E;
 }
```

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <E extends Throwable> void throwAsUnchecked(Exception exception) throws E {
    throw (E) exception;
}
```

And client code will looks like this:

```
public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String arr[] = new String[]{"java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.Strin"};
        Stream.of(arr).forEach(rethrowConsumer(Class::forName));
    }
```

I want to know how does it work. It is really unclear for me.

lets research **rethrowConsumer:**

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> rethrowConsumer(Consumer_WithExceptions<T, E> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            consumer.accept(t);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throwAsUnchecked(exception);
        }
    };
}
```

and throwAsUnchecked signature look slike

```
private static <E extends Throwable> void throwAsUnchecked(Exception exception) throws E {
```

Please clarify this mess.

### P.S.

I localized that magic happens inside `throwAsUnchecked` because following snippet correct

```
   public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> rethrowConsumer(Consumer_WithExceptions<T, E> consumer) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                throw new Exception();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throwAsUnchecked(exception);
            }
        };
    }
```

But following not

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> rethrowConsumer(Consumer_WithExceptions<T, E> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            consumer.accept(t);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new Exception();
            //throwAsUnchecked(exception);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: And just for the record: you only use "_" for SOME_CONSTANT. It doesnt go into any other kind of name.

Comment: @GhostCat it is copy paste from linked topic

Comment: @GhostCat actually I can't understand why compiler interpret Throwable as RuntimeException

Comment: That is to be found in the linked question I have in my answer. To be specific, you want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039011/1531124

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java compiler understands that `Class.forName()` throws a **checked** exception. And that needs to somehow be handled.  But when *catching* that **checked** exception and making it look like it gets wrapped into a  `RuntimeException` for example - you resolve the *compilation* problem. By taking *away* the "thing" that the compiler complains about.

Please note: the compiler does **not** understand that invoking `throwAsUnchecked(exception)` will **always** throw up. In other words: by making a **method** call here, there is actually *no* code inside that method body that *must* throw. Of course this doesn't change the runtime situation. In the end, there is still an exception thrown - and surprisingly not a RuntimeException, but an instance of ClassNotFoundException.

The core point is that `<E extends Throwable>` translates into a RuntimeException (for the compiler). And that part is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038649/java-sneakythrow-of-exceptions-type-erasure)!

And because of that, the second version of `foo()` can be written like:

```
public void foo() { ...
```

there is no more need to declare *throws ClassNotFoundException*!

In other words: this approach works by "tricking" the compiler into thinking that the exception that gets thrown is an *unchecked* one. And that trick itself is rooted in generics/type-erasure.

Comment: The linked explanation covers the technical part of type erasure, in other words, the Java byte code. From the Java *language* point of view, you have just an *unchecked* operation which opens the possibility of resulting in *heap pollution*, a mismatch between the compile-time type and the actual runtime type, which includes the possibility to have a checked exception where the compile-time type is `RuntimeException`. So the actual runtime behavior is not a violation of the language specification.